# When do we need [OptionalField]?

Tags: c#, serialization, versioning, binaryformatter

I have a serializable class in some library assembly.
also I have to projects referencing this assembly.
One project serializes an instance of my class,
other project serializes this instance of my class.

I copied dll of this assembly into some backup folder to get ability to restore an old version.

I added new field in my class.
I serialized an instance of my updated class.
Then I restored old version of my class and deserialized the instance.
BinaryFormatter works well and doesn't throw an exception.

Do we need an [optionalField] attribute?

**Library**

```
using System;
namespace SerializationFramework
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Field { get; set; }
        //public string NewField { get; set; }//added in Version 2, without [OptionalField] attribute

        public MyClass()
        {
            Field = "test";
            //NewField = "newField";
        }

        //for checking versions
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Version 1");//comment after adding a new field
            //Console.WriteLine("Version 2");//uncomment after adding a new field
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Serializing**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using SerializationFramework;

namespace Serialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binaryF = new BinaryFormatter();
            var obj = new MyClass();
            using (var f = File.Create(@"C:\temp\oleg.txt"))
            {
                binaryF.Serialize(f, obj);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Serialized!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Deserializing**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using SerializationFramework;

namespace Deserialization
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binaryF = new BinaryFormatter();
            MyClass obj;
            using (var f = File.Open(@"c:\temp\oleg.txt", FileMode.Open))
            {
                obj = (MyClass) binaryF.Deserialize(f);
            }

            //CheckingVersion
            var obj2 = new MyClass();
            obj2.Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not a very sensible test.  If you don't need the field then don't add it.

Comment: what cases do we need [optionalField] attribute in?

Comment: Deserialize old data when you added fields to the class.  The old data is not going to provide a value for NewField, kaboom.  Unless you mark it optional.

Comment: @HansPassant I checked it. New Fields get a null value. BinaryFormatter doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: See [Deserializing a newer version of an object from an older version of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718306/3744182).  But are you maybe using [tag:unity3d]?

Comment: @dbcI don't use unity3d